# SQL 2008 Mirroring Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mirroring

I currently have mirroring setup between three computers, principle, mirror, and witness. During the day, all these systems are fine; they failover with the failover command, and the failover when unplugging any of the stations. My problem is at night I lose Quorum between the three stations, and the only way to get it back up is to restart the witness SQL Server. The worst thing about losing Quorum is that all stations revert to recovery mode which renders the database unusable. It's almost as if the router connecting all the stations went down.

I have tried computer names and IP addresses without any luck. I have similar setups running at a bunch of other customers, so I don't think it's the way we have setup the SQL servers or mirroring. I have the router on a UPS with serge protection and the router has been replaced multiple times, so I know it's not the router. The mirror station has been replaced, hardware and software, because of some other issues that are still occurring. My only other solution is to replace the witness, but if this doesn't work, I'm all out of ideas.

Below is a log file of the error that is being produced when quorum fails. This error message is shown on all of the SQL Servers.

**09/09/2009 10:07:48,spid20s,Unknown,Database mirroring connection error 4 'An error occurred while receiving data: '64(The specified network name is no longer available.)'.' for 'TCP://Silver1:15111'.**

09/09/2009 10:07:48,spid20s,Unknown,Error: 1474 Severity: 16 State: 1.

09/09/2009 10:06:16,spid19s,Unknown,Database mirroring connection error 2 'DNS lookup failed with error: '11001(No such host is known.)'.' for 'TCP://Silver2:15111'.

09/09/2009 10:06:16,spid19s,Unknown,Error: 1474 Severity: 16 State: 1.

Also note that this setup is not using certificates or anything. All the users have the same username and passwords, so I know this is a working solution without having to be on the domain.

Comment: This is a good question for http://serverfault.com

Comment: I have never heard of serverefault.com before. It looks a lot like stack overflow, so I assume that they are one in the same. Is there a way for me to move my question there, or should I just copy and paste?

Comment: You question will be migrated automatiocally, don't bother to copy/paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'DNS lookup failed with error:
>   '11001(No such host is known.)'.' for
>   'TCP://Silver2:15111'.

This pretty much sums up everything. Your networking guys better have an explanation why the DNS name 'Silver2' is lost.

Comment: I am the network guy... and I don't have a good explination why the DNS name is lost *lol*. Initially I thought that was the problem, but while my quorum is broken, I can still ping other stations using the name and also telnet into the endpoint mirroring port.

Comment: Well, I'm the guy who wrote the mirroring endpoint code at MS :) If the OS is reporting the DNS lookup error, I gotta take the OS word over yours, no offense. Is the name resolved through DNS or through WINS? Is there anything specific about when it happens (certain time, under load etc). Did you follow any DNS troubleshooting guide to isolate the issue? Ultimately, can you hardcode the name resolution in the `hosts` file?

Comment: Looking at your first answer, the error that you quoted is right, I have lost connection with station 2, the mirror. Sorry, some times I skim through too quickly and miss important details like that. I don't mind that I lose connection to the mirror; that's a different problem altogether. what I am concerned about is that principle and witness are running, so quorum should still be active, and I should still have one active server.

Comment: I do understand what SQL is complaining about, but I can't figure out why. The endpoint ports are opened and accepting connections, I can connect through SQL management studio, I can do everything, and everything seems perfect. It's almost like something gets locked on the witness(if that makes any sense). Once I restart the Witness, everything is great. Also, What really confuses me is that I used IP address, so why are the SQL errors using computer names? No where in my Quorum setup do I mention any computer names, so that's really confusing me at this point.

Comment: Note that the principal and mirror are reporting to the witness the name of their partner. So if mirror knows the principal by the nickname 'Silver2', then it will ask the witness 'Are you connected to Silver2?'. So you better be consistent and use the same names everywhere, don't mix names and IPs. Also the mirroring protocol is looking up its own machine name at each endpoint and uses it to validate the peer's request. The best option is to use FQDNs as partner and witness name everywhere when you set up mirroring.

Comment: What was happening is that we were having some issues with rebooting stations. Since this is a hospitality industry, the poll displays had a bad driver that was screwing everything up,